# When we use Nuxt and Vuex Store, will the values be shared between different pages?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuex

We want to share values between different pages. We tried it in the following ways.

On the same page, State returned the correct value, but on different pages, State was not set. Are we doing something wrong? Or is Vuex Store not able to share values between pages?

*We have replaced them with simplified codes for this question. The codes that are causing the problem are more complex.*

`/store/index.js`

```js
const NOT_SET = null

export const state = () => ({
  value: NOT_SET,
})

export const mutations = {
  setValue(state, value) {
    state.value = value
  },
}
```

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['value']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setValue(100)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setValue']),
  },
}
</script>
```

`/pages/_XXX/index.vue`

```html
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['value']),
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: My guess is you are not using `nuxt-link`'s thoughout but instead a normal `a` tag, or your directly visiting the page, `pages/_XXX/index.vue` has no code to set the value

Comment: Ah! Yes. We use `a` tags for links. We'll try that.

Comment: Nice guess @LawrenceCherone! `a` tags (with a `target="_blank"`) are only to be used when you want to open some external webpage, otherwise if you want to move inside of your Nuxt app, you should use `nuxt-link`.

Comment: Thank you, @LawrenceCherone!
With `nuxt-link` we could solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `a` tags because those will wipe the whole SPA each time. If you're in a Vue context, you need to use the Vue router, hence `nuxt-link` is mandatory if you want to keep the app during the whole time.

It will also greatly improve the performance of the whole website.

Because otherwise, Vuex is totally able to share the state across all the page. It's meant to share it a cross the whole Vue app in fact.

Comment: Thank you, @kissu.
We understand the difference between `nuxt-link` and `a` tag.